# Deleting a node in a singly linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

Please critique the following code on removing a node from a singly linked list, at the moment it seems to me like the code is quite clunky.

```c
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

Node* create(int A[], int n){
    Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node *temp = NULL;
    Node *tail;
    head->data = A[0];
    head->next = NULL;
    tail = head;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
        temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        temp->data = A[i];
        temp->next = NULL;
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    return head;
}

void delete(Node** head, int index) {
    Node* temp;
    Node* curr;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    curr = *head;
    int pos;
    if (*head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (index == 0) {
        temp = curr->next;
        *head = temp;
        free(curr);
    }
    else {
        for (pos = 0; pos < index; pos++) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        prev->next = curr->next;

        free(curr);
    }


}

int main(){
    int A[] = {3, 5, 7, 9, 10};
    Node *head = create(A, 5);
    delete(&head, 1);
    return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Mark variables that will remain constant as `const`.
- Initialise variables right away when they're created, if possible. You're just adding one extra line with no benefit.
- Limit the scope of variables by creating them only when they're required, not at the top. They'll go unused in certain conditions. Also one won't have to sanity check the whole function to see if the variable has been modified since it was created.
- Use a more descriptive function name. `del_node_at_index` is even better.

```
void delete_node(Node **head, const int index)
{
  // Initialise curr when it's defined. 
  Node *curr = *head;

  if (head == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  if (index == 0) {
    // Keep the scope of temp limited.
    // Initialise temp when it's defined.
    Node *temp = curr->next;
    *head = temp;
    free(curr);
  }
  else {
    // Keep the scope of prev limited. 
    Node *prev;
    // Define pos if and when needed.
    for (int pos = 0; pos < index; pos++) { 
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
    }
    prev->next = curr->next;

    free(curr);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your code for 'delete' do if index is larger than the number of items in the list??? If it is negative?

Comment: yes i have to fix that too

Comment: @user1666959 I suppose that is a question for PyWalker27 (which they replied to) . I didn't check the correctness of the algorithm.

Comment: @PyWalker27 Is the `index` a one-based indexing or zero-based ? i.e.: if you want to delete the first node, would you pass `0` or `1` as the `index` argument ? I'd suggest keeping it zero-based.

Comment: I would pass 0.

Answer (score 5):

@akki covered most of what can be done, however, the best reason to rename the function is that C can be easily ported to C++, and `delete` is a key word in the C++ language. Avoid using C++ key words in C when possible.

Comment: oo i didn't notice that!

Comment: @PyWalker27 that's what code reviews are for.